# System of Difference Equations, Decoupling

Tags: recurrence-relations, economics

I have the nonhomogenous systen of difference equations with $ 0<\beta<1$:
$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}d_{t+1}\\e_{t+1}\end{bmatrix}}_\text{$X_{t+1}$} =\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-1&\frac{1}{\beta}\end{bmatrix}}_\text{$\Phi$}\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}d_t\\e_t\end{bmatrix}}_\text{$X_t$}+\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}}_\text{=A}s_t$$
I want to decouple the system into:
$$Y_{t+1}=\Lambda Y_t+B s_t $$ 
Where $Q$ are the eigenvectors of $\Phi$,  $Y_t=Q^{-1}X_t$ and $B=Q^{-1}A$ and the eigenvalues:$$\Lambda=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&0\\0&\lambda_2\end{bmatrix}$$
Then I want to solve the decoupled system with the larger eigenvalue.

EDIT:
I think I figured out a step:
$$Y_{1,t+1}=\lambda_1 Y_{1,t} $$
$$Y_{2,t+1}=\lambda_2 Y_{2,t} + z_t$$
With $\lambda_2=\frac{1}{\beta}$ being larger I use:
$$Y_{2,t+1}= \frac{1}{\beta}Y_{2,t} + z_t$$
But then how do I solve this, if it's still depending on two periods?

---

**What I have thus far:**
$$\lambda_1=1,\lambda_2=\frac{1}{\beta}$$
$$Q=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1-\beta}{\beta}&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$Q^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\beta}{1-\beta}&0 \\ -\frac{\beta}{1-\beta}&1\end{bmatrix}$$
And when I combine everything I get:
$$Q^{-1}X_{t+1}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\beta}{1-\beta}&0 \\ -\frac{\beta}{1-\beta}&\frac{1}{\beta}\end{bmatrix}X_t+\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}s_t$$

- Is this system already decoupled?
- How can I solve this with the larger eigenvalue (which is $\lambda_2=\frac{1}{\beta}$ since $\beta<1$)?
  Both eigenvalues are still contained in the equation, so I just don't get how you could solve it without both of them.

I'm very gratefull for any help or advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

$$
Q = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -\frac{\beta -1}{\beta } \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\ \ \ \Lambda = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{\beta } & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\ \ \ \delta_k = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1
\end{array}
\right)s_k
$$

we have

$$
y_{k+1} = Q\cdot\Lambda\cdot Q^{-1}y_k + \delta_k
$$

or

$$
Q^{-1}y_{k+1} = \Lambda\cdot Q^{-1}y_k + Q^{-1}\delta_k
$$

or

$$
Y_{k+1} = \Lambda\cdot Y_k + d_k
$$

with solution

$$
Y_k = \Lambda^{k-1}Y_0 + \Lambda^{k-1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\Lambda^{-j}d_j
$$

and finally

$$
y_k = Q\cdot\left( \Lambda^{k-1}Q^{-1}y_0 + \Lambda^{k-1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\Lambda^{-j}Q^{-1}\delta_j\right)
$$

or

$$
y_k = M^{k-1}y_0 + \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}M^{k-j-1}\delta_j
$$